# Htaccess regular expression challenge

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write an .htaccess regex, but still can't make it. I spent many hours trying to figure out the way. Of course, with regex, it is hard to find an exact answer. That's why I would really appreciate your help.

The scenario is: there is a script (WordPress plugin) making a POST request to my API gateway which looks like:

```
https://example.com/?edd_action=check_license&item_id=111&license=UN_222&url=some.url.com
```

Everything was working, but there was an API update on my end and now it won't execute it.
However, after doing multiple tests, I discovered that the same request works when executed this way:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?edd_action=check_license&item_id=111&license=UN_222&url=some.url.com
```

Because there are many people who have installed the WordPress plugin and their license was deactivated, they cannot do an automatic update, and the only way is to redirect the request to the one that will make their plugin active.

The problem to be solved is how we can redirect post requests from:

```
https://example.com/?edd_action=check_license&item_id=111&license=UN_222&url=some.url.com
```

to:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?edd_action=check_license&item_id=111&license=UN_222&url=some.url.com
```

Using htaccess regex rules.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I forgot to add that all variables will be different within each request except edd_action=check_license

Comment: Is the "redirected" request to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` also expected to be a POST request or GET?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this redirect rule at top of your .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^edd_action=check_license&item_id=[^&]+&license=[^&]+&url=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [L,R=302,NE]

# other WP .htaccess code goes below this
```

This rule will redirect landing page URI to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` if given query string pattern matches successfully.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i think we are almost there. How we can match license=UN_222? The same way ? license=[^&] ? All variables will be different within each request except  edd_action=check_license

Comment: Ok sure, try my updated rule now.